# Prove that we can always choose $m$ such that $s^m \le t^n \lt s^{m+1}$ for $s,m,n,t$ being positive integers

Tags: number-theory, inequality

I'm currently reading through [these](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/kleeman/infolect1.pdf) lecture notes on deriving the Shannon entropy axiomatically, and I've gotten stuck at what I think *should* be an easy step. It's on Equation (2.1), which says that we can have:

$$s^m \le t^n \lt s^{m+1},$$ for $s,m,n,t$ being positive integers. It's stated that this can always be done by choosing an appropriate $m$ (so the other variables are fixed). However, I can't seem to prove this. I don't see why this should always be true (basically, I'm imaging a fixed value $t^n$ and trying to have an interval described by $\left[s^m, s^{m+1} \right]$ that always contains $t^n$). Does anyone have tips for approaching this?

Comment: One needs $\lvert s\rvert > 1$ in that.

Comment: Take the (disjoint!) union of $[s^m, s^{m+1})$.

Comment: Choose $m = \max \lbrace k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ }| \text{ } s^k \leq t^n \rbrace$. (why does it exist ?)

Comment: One also needs $t \neq 0$ if $s > 0$.

Comment: Trivially easy for positive $t$ if $m$ is a sufficiently large odd positive integer and $s$ is a negative integer. Did you mean to restrict matters to positive integers?

Comment: @KeithBackman Yes, I meant to restrict this to positive integers. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe It exists because if we take $s\in \mathbb{N}$, then $t^n$ is finite, so it has to bound the sequence of powers of $s$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just consider the case $s,t > 0$. The general case (whenever it is true) can be done in the same way.

Observe $(0, \infty) = \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} [s^m, s^{m+1})$. Since $t^n \in (0,\infty)$, there exists some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $t^n \in [s^m, s^{m+1})$.

A general tip in mathematics is to try concrete examples. In our case we might take a random example such as $s = 3, t = 2, n = 10$, so we would look for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $3^m \leq 2^{10} < 3^{m+1}$. The naive idea is to try out the first few examples until we "hit" an interval that contains $2^5$. We would see that $m = 1$ doesn't work and that we need larger $m$. We would keep going until we eventually find that $m = 6$ works - and that we have hit every integer from $3^1$ to $3^7$. The formal argument above is only a formalization of this thought process.